# Apple script to restart and after restart quit application

Tags: macos, applescript

This apple script is saved as application Mac_restart.app 
After running Mac_restart.app mac restart and after restart this app is still on Dock as running app and i can click on restart it again, I have added the application quit but it didn't work.
i want to quite this app after restart and dont want on Dock as open application.
what i missing? kindly help.

if i don't put *try* in entire script app will throw error after some time AppleEvent time out (-1712) and i can see Edit option which i don't want that's why it put whole on *try* and if i put try on above handlers it will still continue to reboot i want until i press restart  it shroud not restart. 
 Below is the final app which is not quit the app after restart. rest working fine.

```
try
    with timeout of 400 seconds
        tell application "Finder"
            display dialog "Create Folder & Restart." buttons {"Cancel", "Ok"} default button 1 with icon 0 with title "Create Folder & Restart" giving up after 400
            if the button returned of the result is "Cancel" then
                return
            end if
        end tell
    end timeout

    try
        do shell script "mkdir -p /Volumes/MAC/Users/jack/Desktop/2014"
        do shell script "mkdir -p /Volumes/MAC/Users/jack/Desktop/2015"
        do shell script "mkdir -p /Volumes/MAC/Users/jack/Desktop/2016"
        do shell script "mkdir -p /Volumes/MAC/Users/jack/Desktop/2017"
    end try

    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        display dialog "Click on Restart." with icon 0 buttons ("Restart") giving up after 60
    end tell
    tell application "Finder"
        restart
    end tell
end try
```

Answer (score 0):

If the script is saved as application use the `on quit` handler

```
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        display dialog "Computer restart " with title "Restart Mac" with icon 0 buttons ("Restart Now")
    end tell
    quit
end run

on quit
    tell application "Finder" to restart
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: its not working same it still on dock after restart and ask me to restart again.

Comment: It's probably not related to the script syntax. Prove it with `beep` instead of `restart`. The script will quit.

Comment: If the whole script is in `try` is not taking `on quit` `on run` ..!!!!




`try
on run
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        display dialog "Computer restart " with title "Restart Mac" with icon 0 buttons ("Restart Now")
    end tell
    quit
end run

on quit
    tell application "Finder" to restart
    continue quit
end quit
end try`

Comment: My suggestion doesn't contain any `try`. Do not put entire handlers in a `try` block anyway.

Comment: If you mean the desktop folder of the current user it's just `/Users/jack/Desktop/2014` (no leading `Volumes/<diskname>`). The startup volume is represented by the first slash. And you can create the 4 folders in one line: `do shell script "mkdir -p /Users/jack/Desktop/{2014,2015,2016,2017}"`

Comment: ok that is good..thx.. i will try. But main thing is after restart it should not show App on dock. It should quit.